# Trying to sum up 4 numbers in a file that follow a certain string

Tags: python, function, sum

I'm having trouble with this function where I want to sum up the numbers 772, 357, 155 and 141 (to equal 1425).

The numbers follow a string 'FO203509.1' in the following input file:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
def sum_nt(input):
    for line in input:
        line=line.rstrip()
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            line=line.split()
            subject_id=line[1]
            a=line[3]
            if subject_id=='FO203509.1':
                sum(a)
    return a

ans3=sum_nt(input)
print(ans3)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
local variable a referenced before assignment
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You simply used a somewhere else in your code. Just use another variable name.

Comment: Just tried this, still not working, no matter what I change the variable name to. Still get 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment' (I changed the variable name to x in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick'n dirty:

```
def sum_nt(input):
  values = []
  for line in input:
    if not line.startswith('#'):
      split_line = line.split()
      subject_id = split_line[1]
      if subject_id == 'FO203509.1':
        values.append(int(split_line[3]))
  return sum(values)
```

What happens here:

- There's a list called 'values' which is originally empty. We want to achieve that the values which you would like to sum up (i.e., the ones following "FO203509.1") end up in this list. This is done by values.append()
- sum() then finally computes the sum of everything in 'values'. Note that sum() works on iterables, not on single values. E.g.: sum([1,2,3]) returns 6. sum(a) doesn't work as  is a string value, not an iterable.
- a=line[3] --> this gives you the 4th element of the split string as *string*. In your case, this needs to be interpreted as (integer) number, as you want to calculate a sum of numbers. Therefore, you need to convert it like this: a = int(line[3]). Note: this works only if line[3] indeed contains string which can be interpreted as a number, else you'll get a ValueError. int("42") works, int("foo") doesn't.
- One more hint: be careful about variable reuse. You used "line" for both the original line and the split line. Having separate variables (e.g., "line" and "split_line") improves readability and helps you to understand better what's going on.

Comment: You should explain what was wrong in the OP's code not just code dump and run.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted to do, hadn't thought about using append(), still getting my head around all the functions. But I still don't know what was wrong with my code, why was I getting the error? I feel like to improve, I need to understand where I'm going wrong but thank you!

Comment: Added some comments. I'd recommend though to install IPython (https://ipython.org/) and go through a couple of Python tutorials to get a better feeling for how this all works.

Answer (score 1):

Your "for" section and "return a" need to be indented in order to match up with your function definition.

e.g.

```
def sum_nt(input):
    for line in input:
        line=line.rstrip()
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            line=line.split()
            subject_id=line[1]
            a=line[3]
            if subject_id=='FO203509.1':
                sum(a)
    return a

ans3=sum_nt(input)
print(ans3)
```

Comment: Sorry, I had it indented like this myself, when I copy and pasted I mucked the indentation up, I'll fix it now

Comment: Okay. Can you describe more about the error; which line is it referring to in this definition?

Comment: I think your issue is to do with your sum(a) which wouldn't work without assigning the value sum(a) to a variable.

Comment: It says there's an error in the lines: ans3=sum_nt(input) and return a

Comment: Also, tried assigning it to a variable, same error, except with the new variable!

Comment: What do you see if you print a after a=line[3]?